# reliable export of journalctl logs

Tags: syslog, journald, journalctl

I search a way for a reliable export of journalctl logs.

I could use the `--since=...` option, but this is a bit fuzzy.

In my case a script would call `journalctl --output=json` every ten minutes.

I don't want to miss a single line and (if possible) I would like to avoid duplicate lines.

Some days after asking this question I came across RELP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_Event_Logging_Protocol

Comment: Why did you decide to use `--output=json` instead of `--output=export` if you want a "reliable" export?

Comment: @VictorYarema I like the json output. It is repliable, but I want to avoid duplicates. Why is `--output=export` better?

Answer (score 10):

You can install a syslog daemon such as rsyslog (the default on Red Hat derived systems). This will log all journal entries in a more backward compatible manner, and of course you can specify a custom log for whatever you wish.

If you don't need logs exported in real time, you can use `journalctl --since` as some people have mentioned. You can run it daily at midnight with the time specifier `yesterday` to get exactly 24 hours of logs.

---

If you really need to get logs at short intervals and don't want to miss a single entry, then you need to learn about the *cursor*. For each log entry journalctl will provide a cursor which can be used to skip to exactly that log entry with `--cursor`, or the immediately following log entry with `--after-cursor`. Consider the following sample JSON:

```
{
    "__CURSOR" : "s=6ad7dcf190f3409c8bf8086fec22888c;i=286c44;b=6b134acc25e94d69b4713422b7c773be;m=46f7a97d25;t=55f5e93131a32;x=aecce3d8b96df5dc",
    "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1512234682620466",
    "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "304802790693",
    "_BOOT_ID" : "6b134acc25e94d69b4713422b7c773be",
    "PRIORITY" : "6",
    "_MACHINE_ID" : "770056613d554df2abcb7757ba2e6270",
    "_HOSTNAME" : "dalaran.example.us",
    "_PID" : "1",
    "_UID" : "0",
    "_SELINUX_CONTEXT" : "system_u:system_r:init_t:s0",
    "_GID" : "0",
    "_CAP_EFFECTIVE" : "3fffffffff",
    "SYSLOG_FACILITY" : "3",
    "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "systemd",
    "_TRANSPORT" : "journal",
    "_COMM" : "systemd",
    "_EXE" : "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd",
    "_CMDLINE" : "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 25",
    "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/init.scope",
    "_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "init.scope",
    "_SYSTEMD_SLICE" : "-.slice",
    "CODE_FILE" : "../src/core/unit.c",
    "CODE_LINE" : "1505",
    "CODE_FUNC" : "unit_status_log_starting_stopping_reloading",
    "MESSAGE_ID" : "de5b426a63be47a7b6ac3eaac82e2f6f",
    "MESSAGE" : "Stopping OpenSSH server daemon...",
    "UNIT" : "sshd.service",
    "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1512234682615526"
}
```

For your purposes, the `__CURSOR` is an opaque blob. Just capture the value from the *last* log entry you receive on one call to `journalctl` and feed it to the *next* call:

```
journalctl --output=json --after-cursor="s=6ad7dcf190f3409c8bf8086fec22888c;i=286c44;b=6b134acc25e94d69b4713422b7c773be;m=46f7a97d25;t=55f5e93131a32;x=aecce3d8b96df5dc" ...
```

Comment: "This will log all journal entries" it does not seem like just having  rsyslog installed is sufficient for this. Seems like it requires further configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Use the --since option.  To get logs from the last 10 minutes, just use:

```
--since -10m
```

That will give you logs 10 minutes prior to the current time.  See the man page https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html and this page on time specifications for systemd https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#

Comment: OK, if use `--since -10m` very 10minutes, then I guess some log entries get lost. I could use it every 8 minutes. This would give me some log entries twice .... Could work, but I need to do deduplication :-(

Answer (score 1):

one way of doing it (not very reliable, but can work):

```
$ crontab -l | tail -1
*/10 * * * * journalctl --output=json --since -10m >> journalctl.json
$
```

---

alternative way to do it; (assuming you need to import json output into `elasticsearch`):

- [mheese/journalbeat: Journalbeat is a log shipper from systemd/journald to Logstash/Elasticsearch](https://github.com/mheese/journalbeat)
- [Filebeat: Lightweight Log Analysis & Elasticsearch | Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat)

Answer (score 0):

syslog-ng can read from the journal and export to plain old text files.
You can also setup syslog-ng to send data to other systems (including elasticsearch).

Answer (score 0):

you can create python script for polling journalctl with using `query_unique` function. Probably running as a service could help also, with restart option -- to not to miss anything.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/python-systemd/journal.html